# mysql join table even if the 2nd table return 0 queries?

Tags: mysql, join

I've data like this:

```
table 1
|id|fieldname1|fieldname2|price|

table 2
|id|fieldname3|fieldname4|price|

desired result:
|table1_id|table2_id|fieldname1|fieldname2|fieldname3|fieldname4|table1_min_price|table2_min_price|
```

I basically can do a left join from table 1 to table 2 on (fieldname1=fieldname3) getting the lowest price from each table.

However if table 2 return 0 queries there will not be joining no results at at all.
My intention is if table 2 or table 1 does not have results, it will still join up the table and create the fields with null values..

Any ideas how can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

You may want a FULL OUTER JOIN which will give you either the values from Table1 or the Values from Table2 or Both. But I don't think you can get a row when its Neither

Answer (score 1):

CHANGE 'UNION ALL' TO 'UNION' :

```
SELECT * from 
    (SELECT origin,destination,min(price) as oneway_cheapest FROM farestable_test where flight_type=0  group by origin,destination )as t1 
     LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT origin,destination,min(price) as return_cheapest FROM farestable_test where flight_type=1 group by origin,destination )as t2

ON (t1.origin = t2.origin AND t1.destination=t2.destination)

UNION 

SELECT * from 
    (SELECT origin,destination,min(price) as oneway_cheapest FROM farestable_test where flight_type=0  group by origin,destination )as t1 
     RIGHT JOIN
    (SELECT origin,destination,min(price) as return_cheapest FROM farestable_test where flight_type=1 group by origin,destination )as t2

ON (t1.origin = t2.origin AND t1.destination=t2.destination)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can accomplish full outer join as below :

```
select *
from table1 left outer join table2 on(fieldname1=fieldname3)
union 
select *
from table1 right outer join table2 on(fieldname1=fieldname3)
```

Comment: this way, it will give duplicate values , is there a full outer join possible?

Comment: instead of union all use only union.It works! removes duplicates

Answer (score 0):

Below is the table i've come up with.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `farestable_test` (
  `id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `origin` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `destination` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `flight_type` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `price` float NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



SELECT * from 
    (SELECT origin,destination,min(price) as oneway_cheapest FROM farestable_test where flight_type=0  group by origin,destination )as t1 
     LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT origin,destination,min(price) as return_cheapest FROM farestable_test where flight_type=1 group by origin,destination )as t2

ON (t1.origin = t2.origin AND t1.destination=t2.destination)

UNION ALL

SELECT * from 
    (SELECT origin,destination,min(price) as oneway_cheapest FROM farestable_test where flight_type=0  group by origin,destination )as t1 
     RIGHT JOIN
    (SELECT origin,destination,min(price) as return_cheapest FROM farestable_test where flight_type=1 group by origin,destination )as t2

ON (t1.origin = t2.origin AND t1.destination=t2.destination)
```

What i want to achieve is :

If data is

```
INSERT INTO `farestable_test` (`id`, `origin`, `destination`, `flight_type`, `price`) VALUES
(1, 'syd', 'mky', 0, 100),
(2, 'syd', 'mky', 0, 200),
```

It shows the CORRECT results:

```
origin  destination     oneway_cheapest     origin  destination     return_cheapest
syd     mky     100     null    null    null
```

AND THEN ....

If data is

```
INSERT INTO `farestable_test` (`id`, `origin`, `destination`, `flight_type`, `price`) VALUES
(3, 'syd', 'mky', 1, 300),
(4, 'syd', 'mky', 1, 400);
```

It wil show CORRECT result:

```
origin  destination     oneway_cheapest     origin  destination     return_cheapest
null    null    null    syd     mky     300
```

However if data is below

```
INSERT INTO `farestable_test` (`id`, `origin`, `destination`, `flight_type`, `price`) VALUES
(1, 'syd', 'mky', 0, 100),
(2, 'syd', 'mky', 0, 200),
(3, 'syd', 'mky', 1, 300),
(4, 'syd', 'mky', 1, 400);
```

The result here is WRONG :

```
origin  destination     oneway_cheapest     origin  destination     return_cheapest
syd     mky     100     syd     mky     300
syd     mky     100     syd     mky     300
```

It has duplicate data which is wrong, i cant do a full join without union all with mysql.
Is there a better way?